# Multiline copy paste not working in the MongoDB shell mongosh | Windows

Tags: mongodb, multiline, mongo-shell

I'm new to MongoDB, I was trying to use `insertMany` method and wanted to insert the below documents in a Collection. I copied from notepas++ but the `Mongoshell` gave the errors when I copy pasted. How to copy and paste multiline data in Mongo shell in Windows? Are there any settings that prevent these errors?

```
[
  {
    "departureAirport": "MUC",
    "arrivalAirport": "SFO"
    "airCraft": "A389",
    "distance": 2000,
    "interContinental": true
  }
  {
    "departureAirport": "DEL",
    "arrivalAirport": "YVR"
    "airCraft": "A777",
    "distance": 20000,
    "interContinental": false
  }
]
```

[image]

Expectation: Successful Insert from the `insertMany` method [warning at paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlPr7.png)

Comment: Have you checked to see if this is a valid array of objects? At a glance I see missing commas that need to be fixed

Comment: @user20042973 I see this pop up when I try to paste onto Mongoshell.

Comment: That's shell prompt , you can click on paste it anyway not a mongo issue

Comment: @Navitas28 But I see lots of errors the moment I click on paste it anyway. You can please see the attached error in the question its keeps saying missing semi colon

Comment: As @user20042973 mentioned check your json it seems invalid, use a [json validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate it

Comment: @Navitas28 after correcting the JSON also its the same error.

Comment: @Coding_pundit09 multi-line paste is not an error its a warning from windows shell , after validation your json are you still getting errors like missing comma and semicolon which you were getting earlier

Comment: For disabling the warning you can follow https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7482 link

Comment: @Navitas28 Like I mentioned in the previous comment , yes the errors are still same even after correcting the JSON. It isn't about disabling the warning , its about not getting the error while pasting the valid JSON and I understand the difference between error and warning. Thanks for the link I'll check if it helps

Comment: Can you provide a working example of what you are trying because if json is valid the error shouldn't come you can use https://mongoplayground.net/ to create a example

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue earlier while I was watching udemy video of Maximilian Schwarzmüller for the [Mongodb Course](https://www.udemy.com/course/mongodb-the-complete-developers-guide/)

the resolution to this error is simple,

Step 1: Copy the code from the text editor (like VScode, sublimetext)

[Command Prompt on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs4jH.png)

Step 2: Double click on the command prompt after `db.coll.insertMany(`

[Paste Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkBRw.png)

Step 3: Close the parenthesis ')'

[Closed Parenthesis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z915.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the command breaks when there are several newlines.  Remove newlines before pasting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).